# How to make Http operations from simple ES6 application

Tags: json, http, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest

I am developing simple application without any framework.

How can I do simple Http requests (get/post)?

I know about XMLHttpRequest():

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', false);

xhr.send();

if (xhr.status != 200) {

  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );  
} else {
  alert( xhr.responseText );  
}
```

But maybe there is another way?

- Without any libraries please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to my knowledge, there is nothing in the [es6 specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) that changed the XMLHttpRequest API to make it easier, so it's a no to your question.

You still have to write a few lines to make it more "es6 style", like promisifying it for instance, [like here](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/promisify/):

```
const request = (params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(params.method || "GET", params.url);
        if (params.headers) {
            Object.keys(params.headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, params.headers[key]);
            });
        }
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(params.body);
    });
};
```